# Maximum along axis in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array as follows:

```py
>> custom_array = np.array([[[0.1, 0.4, 0.4],
        [0.3, 0.2, 0.7]],

       [[0.9, 0.4, 0.2],
        [0.5, 0.1, 0.1]]])
>> custom_array.shape
(2,2,3)
```

The above array represents the probability table:

```
| X1    | X2    | X3    | P     |
|----   |----   |----   |-----  |
| 0     | 0     | 0     | 0.1   |
| 0     | 0     | 1     | 0.4   |
| 0     | 0     | 2     | 0.4   |
| 0     | 1     | 0     | 0.3   |
| 0     | 1     | 1     | 0.2   |
| 0     | 1     | 2     | 0.7   |
| 1     | 0     | 0     | 0.9   |
| 1     | 0     | 1     | 0.4   |
| 1     | 0     | 2     | 0.2   |
| 1     | 1     | 0     | 0.5   |
| 1     | 1     | 1     | 0.1   |
| 1     | 1     | 2     | 0.1   |
```

I would like to obtain the indices along axis 0 and 2 which maximize the value along axis=1(second axis). My expected output should be:

(1,0) => Because this combination of X1 and X3 maximize the value of P when X2 = 0

(0,2) => Because this combination of X1 and X3 maximize the value of P when X2 = 1

I've tried the following command:

```py
>>> np.unravel_index(custom_array.argmax(), custom_array.shape)
(1,0,0)
```

This is the correct answer, but I'm unable to figure out how to modify this command to give both the outputs mentioned above.

I would appreciate any hints the community could provide. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get (e.g. print) indices of *max* elements, use the following
code:

```
for i in range(custom_array.shape[1]):
    tbl = np.take(custom_array, i, axis=1)
    ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(tbl), tbl.shape)
    print(f'{i}: {ind}')
```

Details:

- `for i in ...` - iterate over values of *X2*,
- `tbl` - a slice of your source array with particular value of *X2*,
- `np.argmax(tbl)` - the index of max element in a flattened array,
- `np.unravel_index` - convert to indices in the underlying array (*tbl*).

For your data sample the result is:

```
0: (1, 0)
1: (0, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the indices in the slice where X2 is 0, use:

```
from numpy import array, where

array(where(custom_array[:, 0, :] == custom_array[:, 0, :].max())).squeeze()
```

To find the indices in the slice where X2 is 1 use:

```
array(where(custom_array[:, 1, :] == custom_array[:, 1, :].max())).squeeze()
```

To find for an array with any number of values for X2, use:

```
[array(where(custom_array[:, i, :] == custom_array[:, i, :].max())).squeeze() 
 for i in range(custom_array.shape[1])]
```